# How do I solve wmape in R?

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to solve an mixed-integer problem with CVXR in R. Following code is used to solve it:

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 100
p <- 10
beta <- -4:5
X <- matrix(rnorm(n * p), nrow=n)
colnames(X) <- paste0("beta_", beta)
Y <- X %*% beta + rnorm(n)
W <- matrix(data = sample(-10:10,n,replace = TRUE), nrow = n,ncol = 1)
betaHat <- Variable(p)
objective <- Minimize(sum(t(abs(Y - X %*% betaHat))%*%W/sum(t(Y)%*%W)))
problem <- Problem(objective)
result <- solve(problem)
```

This gives the following error:

```
Error in construct_intermediate_chain(object, candidate_solvers, gp = gp) :Problem does not follow DCP rules.
```

Can someone explain how to solve it so? how do I transform this problem into DCP rules? thanks

Comment: The problem is the negative weights. If you can use positive weights then it will work.

Comment: Thks G. Grothendieck. It works!